# Angular Google Map multiple MarkerClusterers

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I never seen any example talking about how to use multiple MarkerClusterers in Angularjs google map.

I created an plunker for my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/TlkZ18IMbWKxI8pdgwko?p=preview

The template looks like this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
    <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" type="cluster" icon="'icon'" >
    </ui-gmap-markers>
    <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers1" coords="'self'" type="cluster" typeOptions='{"title":"Hi I am a Cluster!","gridSize":20,"ignoreHidden":true,"minimumClusterSize":2}' icon="'icon'">
    </ui-gmap-markers>
```

I have problem to make the markercluster work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `doCluster="true"` for the clusterer to actually create the clusters as needed on your plunkr, which is pointing to version 2.0.x of the library:

```js
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 40.1451,
        longitude: -99.6680
      },
      zoom: 4,
      bounds: {}
    };
    $scope.options = {
      mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true
    };

    var createRandomMarker = function(i, bounds, idKey) {
      var lat_min = bounds.southwest.latitude,
        lat_range = bounds.northeast.latitude - lat_min,
        lng_min = bounds.southwest.longitude,
        lng_range = bounds.northeast.longitude - lng_min;

      if (idKey == null) {
        idKey = "id";
      }

      var latitude = lat_min + (Math.random() * lat_range);
      var longitude = lng_min + (Math.random() * lng_range);
      var ret = {
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude,
        title: 'm' + i
      };
      ret[idKey] = i;
      return ret;
    };
    $scope.randomMarkers = [];
    $scope.randomMarkers1 = [];
    // Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.map.bounds;
    }, function(nv, ov) {
      // Only need to regenerate once
      if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          markers.push(createRandomMarker(i, $scope.map.bounds))
        }
        $scope.randomMarkers = markers;
        var markers1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
          markers1.push(createRandomMarker(i, $scope.map.bounds))
        }
        $scope.randomMarkers1 = markers1;
      }
    }, true);
  });
```

```css
        html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            position: relative;
        }

        .angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>

<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org/" ng-app="appMaps">


<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
        <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" doCluster="true" icon="'icon'" >
        </ui-gmap-markers>
        <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers1" coords="'self'" doCluster="true" typeOptions='{"title":"Hi I am a Cluster!","gridSize":20,"ignoreHidden":true,"minimumClusterSize":2}' icon="'icon'">
        </ui-gmap-markers>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
<!--example-->
</body>

</html>
```

On the current version 2.2.1 `doCluster="true"` still works along `type="'cluster'"` since it's still checking for both:

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/dist/angular-google-maps.js#L4982

Please note that you must set `type="'cluster'"` and not `type="cluster"` because it does a strict equals (===) on that and expects it to be a string.

Comment: I thought doCluster has been deprecated. see this http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers

Comment: I added notes regarding that now :)

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation says](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers) `type` parameter has been introduced in `2.1.6` version. It explains why `type="cluster"` is not working as expected in your case, since `2.0.X` library is referenced:

```
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
```

So,for `2.0.X` use  `doCluster`  parameter :

```js
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.map = {
          center: {
              latitude: 40.1451,
              longitude: -99.6680
          },
          zoom: 4,
          bounds: {}
      };
      $scope.options = {
          mapTypeControl: true,
          scaleControl: true,
          streetViewControl: true
      };

      var createRandomMarker = function (i, bounds, idKey) {
          var lat_min = bounds.southwest.latitude,
            lat_range = bounds.northeast.latitude - lat_min,
            lng_min = bounds.southwest.longitude,
            lng_range = bounds.northeast.longitude - lng_min;

          if (idKey == null) {
              idKey = "id";
          }

          var latitude = lat_min + (Math.random() * lat_range);
          var longitude = lng_min + (Math.random() * lng_range);
          var ret = {
              latitude: latitude,
              longitude: longitude,
              title: 'm' + i
          };
          ret[idKey] = i;
          return ret;
      };
      $scope.randomMarkers = [];
      // Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
      $scope.$watch(function () {
          return $scope.map.bounds;
      }, function (nv, ov) {
          // Only need to regenerate once
          if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
              var markers = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                  markers.push(createRandomMarker(i, $scope.map.bounds))
              }
              $scope.randomMarkers = markers;
          }
      }, true);
  });
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

#map_canvas {
            position: relative;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
 <script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script> 

<div id="map_canvas" ng-app="appMaps" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
            <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" doCluster="true" typeoptions='{"title":"","gridSize":20,"ignoreHidden":true,"minimumClusterSize":2}' icon="'icon'">
            </ui-gmap-markers>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

for `2.1.X` or above use `type` parameter:

```js
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.map = {
          center: {
              latitude: 40.1451,
              longitude: -99.6680
          },
          zoom: 4,
          bounds: {}
      };
      $scope.options = {
          mapTypeControl: true,
          scaleControl: true,
          streetViewControl: true
      };

      var createRandomMarker = function (i, bounds, idKey) {
          var lat_min = bounds.southwest.latitude,
            lat_range = bounds.northeast.latitude - lat_min,
            lng_min = bounds.southwest.longitude,
            lng_range = bounds.northeast.longitude - lng_min;

          if (idKey == null) {
              idKey = "id";
          }

          var latitude = lat_min + (Math.random() * lat_range);
          var longitude = lng_min + (Math.random() * lng_range);
          var ret = {
              latitude: latitude,
              longitude: longitude,
              title: 'm' + i
          };
          ret[idKey] = i;
          return ret;
      };
      $scope.randomMarkers = [];
      // Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
      $scope.$watch(function () {
          return $scope.map.bounds;
      }, function (nv, ov) {
          // Only need to regenerate once
          if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
              var markers = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                  markers.push(createRandomMarker(i, $scope.map.bounds))
              }
              $scope.randomMarkers = markers;
          }
      }, true);
  });
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }

#map_canvas {
            position: relative;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
 <script src="http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.1.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script> 

<div id="map_canvas" ng-app="appMaps" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
            <ui-gmap-markers models="randomMarkers" coords="'self'" type="'cluster'" typeoptions='{"title":"","gridSize":20,"ignoreHidden":true,"minimumClusterSize":2}' icon="'icon'">
            </ui-gmap-markers>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```